# How to get the confidence interval for interpolation?

Tags: r, interpolation, curve-fitting

I perform the linear interpolation and specifies where interpolation is to take place. I get the interpolated data, but I don't know how to get the confidence interval for these interpolated data (red) by linear interpolation.
Is there any other way (loess,splines ) to do interpolation meeting two requirements:

1. Specifying where interpolation is to take place
2. getting the interpolated data and confidence interval for interpolated data.

Here is the code that I used.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- 0.4 * x+ rnorm(100, 0, 1)
ptsLin <- approx(x, y, method="linear", xout=seq(-2,2, 0.1))
plot(x, y, xlab=NA, ylab=NA, pch=19, main="Linear interpolation", 
 cex=1.5)
points(ptsLin, pch=16, col="red", lwd=1.5)
lines(ptsLin)
legend(x="bottomleft", c("Data", "linear"), pch=c(19, 16), col=c("black", "red" 
), bg="white")
```

[image]